# Hudson Release failure with error 'Unable to tag SCM'

Tags: maven, svn

When giving release from hudson getting the below error

```
mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.1:prepare (default-cli) on project parent: Unable to tag SCM
Provider message:
The svn tag command failed.
Command output:
svn: E235000: In file 'subversion/libsvn_client/commit_util.c' line 479: assertion failed ((copy_mode_root && copy_mode) || ! copy_mode_root)
/bin/sh: line 1: 23797 Aborted                 (core dumped) svn --username user --password 'pass*123' --no-auth-cache --non-interactive copy --file /tmp/maven-scm-1635387492.commit . http://codeserver.ennovate.com/source-repository/parent/tags/parent-4a.1503.2
```

1. I don't have any existing tag as `/tags/parent-4a.1503.2/`
2. I checked my credential and it was correct

Please help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

We found the same problem. There is one more report here:

https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-users/201201.mbox/%3C2B173B138EFF584C846A48D41EFA3B420190AE53@server.tc.local%3E

Basically, if you have different ways to refer to the subversion server, for example, server and server.domain.com, you checkout a working copy from "server", but in the Maven root POM the SVN configuration points to server.domain.com, you will find this error.

You have to enter the same name in the  elemento in the root POM, and in the svn command used to check-out a project from the Subversion sever.